# How to use mousehover delay in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, delay, mousehover

I am using mousehover for click in c# but I want it to wait 2-3 sec before click and if cursor does not stay on a button for 2 or more seconds, it won't click.

Comment: What technology are you using? WinForms, WPF or some other XAML platform, something else? (Hopefully not HTML/CSS, you can't use C# there)

Comment: use a timer. BTW "provide me the code" is **very** unwelcome behavior here.

Comment: If i use timer here, it will just give a delay.And if i remove the pointer in less than 3sec, it will just click it with a delay

Answer (score 2):

You could implement that functionality by deriving from `Button` class:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MouseHoverDelay
{
    public class HoverButton : Button
    {
        protected System.Timers.Timer timer;

        public bool IsHoverEnabled { get; set; }
        public double Delay { get; set; }

        public event System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler TimerElapsed
        {
            add
            {
                timer.Elapsed += value;
            }
            remove
            {
                timer.Elapsed -= value;
            }
        }

        public HoverButton()
        {
            // defaults: hover trigger enabled with 3000 ms delay
            IsHoverEnabled = true;
            Delay = 3000;

            timer = new System.Timers.Timer
            {
                AutoReset = false,
                Interval = Delay
            };
        }

        protected override void OnMouseEnter(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnMouseEnter(e);

            if (IsHoverEnabled)
            {
                timer.Start();
            }
        }

        protected override void OnMouseLeave(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnMouseLeave(e);

            timer.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

After adding it to the form you need to set it's `Delay` and handler method inside the `InitializeComponent()` method of the form:

```
this.btnHoverTest.Delay = 2000;
this.btnHoverTest.TimerElapsed += timer_Elapsed;
```

And then implement the handler in the form:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MouseHoverDelay
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        // triggers when Delay milliseconds have passed since hovering mouse over control
        protected void timer_Elapsed(object o, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hovered for 2 seconds!");
        }
    }
}
```