# How to implement a delayed PointerEnter event into C# UWP project

Tags: c#, user-interface, uwp

I have been trying to implement a feature into my application where when a user hovers over a Grid item housed within a GridView for a couple seconds it will display a medium sized popup Grid with more details. I have tried a few methods I found online, but I have been running into errors that I am not understanding the root cause of, and I have the feeling there is a much simpler approach to add this feature than what I have found online so far.

First, I tried a [solution I adapted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10892961/how-to-use-mousehover-delay-in-c) by using a derivative class of Grid. I ran into some issues with that that (detailed a bit more in [my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74934555/how-do-i-properly-implement-a-uwp-c-sharp-subclass-of-grid)) with the main issue being that my Timer no longer would trigger and items using my "HoverGrid" data template within the GridView template would no longer show Image as a child item of the HoverGrid. So, I abandoned that approach.

Then I tried to implement the Timer directly in my Page's code-behind, which seemed to work (partially) as it is properly triggering PointerEnter, PointerExit, and TimerElapsed events, however, when trying to manipulate anything UI related in the TimerElapsed event I would get:

System.Exception: 'The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD))'

Here is the XAML:

```
<Page
    x:Class="myproject.Pages.MyPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Height="950"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid x:Name="ContentGrid">
        <ListView
                    x:Name="AreaPanels"
                    Margin="0,10,0,0"
                    HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                    SelectionMode="None">
            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <ItemsStackPanel AreStickyGroupHeadersEnabled="True" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>

            <controls:AdaptiveGridView
                            CanDragItems="True"
                            DesiredWidth="140"
                            ItemHeight="140">
                <controls:AdaptiveGridView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:Name="IconTextTemplate" x:DataType="Image">
                        <Grid
                                        PointerEntered="ImageHoverStart"
                                        PointerExited="ImageHoverEnd">
                            <Image
                                            Opacity="1"
                                            Source="/Assets/Placeholders/sample_image.jpg"
                                            Stretch="UniformToFill" />
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </controls:AdaptiveGridView.ItemTemplate>
                <Grid />
                <Grid />
                <Grid />
                <Grid />
            </controls:AdaptiveGridView>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Code-behind (C#):

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;

namespace myproject.Pages
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MyPage : Page
    {
        //Variables for Grid functions
        public object hoveredGridItem = null;
        public PointerRoutedEventArgs hoveredGridItemArgs = null;
        public System.Timers.Timer hoverTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();

        public event System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler TimerElapsed
        { add { hoverTimer.Elapsed += value; } remove { hoverTimer.Elapsed -= value; } }

        public MyPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            hoverTimer.Enabled = true;
            hoverTimer.Interval = 2000;
            TimerElapsed += OnTimerElapsed;
        }

        private void ImageHoverStart(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Fired: ImageHoverStart");
            hoverTimer.Start();
            hoveredGridItem = sender;
            hoveredGridItemArgs = e;
        }

        private void ImageHoverEnd(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Fired: ImageHoverEnd");
            hoverTimer.Stop();
            hoveredGridItem = null;
            hoveredGridItemArgs = null;
        }

        private void OnTimerElapsed(object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Timer elapsed!");
            hoverTimer.Stop();

            if (hoveredGridItem.GetType().ToString() == "Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid")
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(hoveredGridItem.ToString());
                Debug.WriteLine(hoveredGridItemArgs.ToString());
                //Get the hovered image and associated arguments that were stored
                Grid itm = (Grid)hoveredGridItem;
                PointerRoutedEventArgs f = hoveredGridItemArgs;

                //Get image position and bounds
                //GeneralTransform transform = itm.TransformToVisual(Window.Current.Content);
                //Point coordinatePointToWindow = transform.TransformPoint(new Point(0, 0));
                //Rect winBounds = Window.Current.Bounds;

                //Testing other UI items
                itm.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

                // other UI stuff ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to make references to some UI elements such as Window.Content.Current and other elements (as a workaround) but was still getting the same System.Exception. I understand this has something to do with TimerElapsed being on a different thread than the UI thread and looked around for [how to fix this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19341591/the-application-called-an-interface-that-was-marshalled-for-a-different-thread) but was not able to fix it.

My two issues are that I was not able to fix the thread marshalling issue (some issues with running things async) but more importantly that the solution seemed a bit convoluted, maybe more difficult than it needs to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first to fix the threading issue you have to use the Dispatcher of the UIElement:

```
await itm.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
{
    itm.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
});
```

And second, have you thought about using a tooltip for this? It should be very easy to implement:

```
<Grid Background="Transparent">
    <Image Opacity="1" Source="/Assets/StoreLogo.png" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
    
    <!--Tooltip implementation:-->
    <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
        <Image Source="/Assets/StoreLogo.png"/>
    </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks Frozen - I did end up using ToolTip and it mostly works for what I needed. My only gripe is that I can't put interactable controls in the ToolTip or change the Initial/Timeout delays, but I understand that is by design with UWP and just something I have accepted into my requirements now.